# Meaning and origin of "dressed like a slob"

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

What does the expression "dressed like a slob" mean? Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *slob* is, to put it charitably, a person who aspires to have the energy to be merely untidy some day. It derives from the Irish Gaelic *slab*, meaning *mud*. It connotes laziness, carelessness and boorishness.

One wouldn't expect, say, a crisply ironed shirt or razor-sharp creases in a slob's clothing. Mismatched socks, pizza stains on a socially inappropriate tee shirt, rumpled and ill-fitting trousers, et cetera, would better describe the uniform of the *true* slob, although "dressed like a slob" is a relative phrase -- it means something different in the suit-and-tie world than it does at the ballpark.

Answer (score 1):

A slob is a lazy, slovenly or untidy person. You won't expect a slob to be dressed stylishly.

From the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=slob):

> 1780, "mud, muddy land," from Ir. *slab*
>   "mud," itself probably borrowed from
>   English *slab* "muddy place" (c.1600),
>   from a Scandinavian source (cf.
>   Icelandic *slabb* "sludge"). The meaning
>   "untidy person" is first recorded
>   1861.

The earliest reference I found of "dressed like a slob" is from 1919's [*The Century*](http://books.google.com/books?id=zbIGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22dressed%20like%20a%20slob%22&dq=%22dressed%20like%20a%20slob%22&hl=en&ei=12sPTuSmHZHGtAa_suiQBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=18&ved=0CHAQ6AEwETg8) illustrated monthly magazine (volume 99):

> Her face flamed, and she glided over
>   to her mother, sobbing out, "Oy, Mama,
>   I 'm dressed like a slob!" Mirke, who
>   happened to be busy with a peasant
>   customer, was startled out of her
>   wits.